# How to disable Geo backup policy in Azure SQL DW using java sdk

Tags: java, sql-server, powershell, azure, sql-data-warehouse

I have created Azure SQL Data warehouse and done pause and resume actions using [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java) SDK

Now I want to disable Geo backup policy when creation of Azure SQL Data warehouse.

How can I do it using Java SDK?

Refer below image for Geo backup policy in Azure SQL Data warehouse.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Azure Rest API to do this.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/***********/resourceGroups/shui156/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/shui156/databases/shui156/geoBackupPolicies/Default?api-version=2014-04-01
```

Body:

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/***********/resourceGroups/shui156/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/shui156/databases/shui156/geoBackupPolicies/Default",
  "name": "Default",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/geoBackupPolicies",
  "location": "East US",
  "kind": null,
  "properties": {
    "state": "Disabled",
    "storageType": null
  }
}
```

Comment: As I am doing all operations using Java SDK - https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java. Is there a way to do using that?

Comment: Sorry, I give a wrong api. I update it. I test it on my lab, it works fine. I will test Azure Java SDK.

Comment: @karan I check the [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.sql._sql_warehouse) for data warehouse. It seems that Azure does not provide this sdk.

Comment: @karan If possible, I suggest you could call Azure rest api. In fact, java sdk also call rest api.

Comment: I have python has this parameter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.sql.operations.geobackuppoliciesoperations?view=azure-python  It means python could modify this. But I find article java seems does not support this.